Lie derivative with respect to the Lie bracket equation $\mathscr{L}_V \mathscr{L}_W A - \mathscr{L}_W \mathscr{L}_V A =\mathscr{L}_{[V,W]} A$
This is Problem 12-11 from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.
Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, $A$ is a smooth covariant tensor field on $M$, and $V,W$ are smooth vector fields on $M$. Show that
$$\mathscr{L}_V \mathscr{L}_W A - \mathscr{L}_W \mathscr{L}_V A =\mathscr{L}_{[V,W]} A.$$
The hint says to use induction on the rank of $A$, beginning with the formula
$$(\mathscr{L}_V A)(X) = V(A(X))- A([V,X])$$ for smooth vector fields $X$.
However, I am really struggling to show how this holds even in the one form case. And even after assuming it, I don't know how this extends to the general case by induction. I would greatly appreciate if someone could provide a proof that doesn't rely on Cartan's formula, which the book hasn't discussed yet.

You can cook up a proof using the following four ingredients.

Leibniz rule. For any vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ and smooth covariant vector fields $A$ and $B$ on $M$ one gets
$$\mathcal{L}(X)(A\otimes B)=(\mathcal{L}(X)A)\otimes B+A\otimes(\mathcal{L}(X)B).$$

Locality property. For any open subset $U\subseteq M$, vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ and smooth covariant tensor field $A$ on $M$ one gets that:
$$(\mathcal{L}(X)A)|_U=\mathcal{L}(X|_X)(A|_U).$$

Local expression of smooth covariant tensor field. Given a smooth covariant vector field $A$ on $M$, around each $p\in M$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ such that
$$A|_U=\sum_i g_i(\mathrm{d}f^i_1)\otimes\ldots\otimes(\mathrm{d}f^i_k).$$

Lie derivative of functions and exact $1$-forms. For any $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$, one gets that
$$\mathcal{L}(X)(f)=Xf\quad\text{and}\quad\mathcal{L}(X)(\mathrm{d}f)=\mathrm{d}(Xf).$$


As a consequence, the proof of the identity you are considering, namely
$$\mathcal{L}(X)\mathcal{L}(Y)A-\mathcal{L}(Y)\mathcal{L}(X)A=\mathcal{L}([X,Y])A,\tag{$\star$}$$
reduces to prove it when $A$ is a function or an exact one form. Finally, you can easily see that, if $A=f$ or $A=\mathrm{d}f$, for some $f\in C^\infty$, then ($\star$) descends from the very definition of the Lie bracket of two vector fields as the commutator of the corresponding algebra derivation of $C^\infty(M)$.
I hope it helps.

I've just been doing that and at the beginning of the 'journey' I prefer very basic proofs, so I share it here if it could help anyone. I will be using following two identities for Lee derivatives of vector fields:
$$(1)\mathcal{L}_XY=[X,Y] \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)\mathcal{L}_{[X,Y]}Z = \mathcal{L}_X(\mathcal{L}_YZ) - \mathcal{L}_Y(\mathcal{L}_XZ)$$
and for Lee derivatives of function along vector field:  $$(3)\mathcal{L}_Xf = Xf  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)\mathcal{L}_{[X,Y]}f = \mathcal{L}_X(\mathcal{L}_Yf) - \mathcal{L}_Y(\mathcal{L}_Xf)$$
Let's split left side of your equation with your hint:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_V{(\mathcal{L}_WA) (Z_1,...,Z_k)} &= V(\mathcal{L}_WA(Z_1,...,Z_k)) - \sum_i^k\mathcal{L}_WA(Z_1,...,[V,Z_i],...,Z_k)\\
&=V\Bigg(W\bigg(A(Z_1,...,Z_k) - \sum_i^kA(Z_1,...,[W,Z_i]...,Z_k)\bigg)\Bigg)\\
&-\sum_i^k\mathcal{L}_WA(Z_1,...,[V,Z_i],...,Z_k)\\
&=V\bigg(W\big(A(Z_1,...,Z_k)\big)\bigg) - \sum_i^kV\big(A(Z_1,...,[W,Z_i]...,Z_k)\big)\\
&-\sum_i^k\mathcal{L}_WA(Z_1,...,[V,Z_i],...,Z_k)\\
&=\color{blue}{\mathcal{L}_V(\mathcal{L}_W(A(Z_1,...,Z_k)))}\color{red}{- \sum_i^kV\big(A(Z_1,...,[W,Z_i]...,Z_k)\big)} \tag{$e2$}\\
&\color{red}{-\sum_i^k\mathcal{L}_WA(Z_1,...,[V,Z_i],...,Z_k)}, 
\end{align*}
where first equation follows from your hint, for $\mathcal{L}_V$, second from your hint for $\mathcal{L}_W$, third from k-linearity of $A$ and last from (3) for real-valued functions $A(Z_1,...,Z_k)$ and so nested $(\mathcal{L}_WA)(Z_1,...,Z_k)$.
Similarly we have:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_W{(\mathcal{L}_VA) (Z_1,...,Z_k)} &=\color{blue}{\mathcal{L}_W(\mathcal{L}_V(A(Z_1,...,Z_k)))}\color{red}{- \sum_i^kW\big(A(Z_1,...,[V,Z_i]...,Z_k)\big)}\tag{$e3$}\\
&\color{red}{-\sum_i^k\mathcal{L}_VA(Z_1,...,[W,Z_i],...,Z_k)} 
\end{align}
Now, note that from (4):
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\mathcal{L}_V(\mathcal{L}_W(A(Z_1,...,Z_k)))} - \color{blue}{\mathcal{L}_W(\mathcal{L}_V(A(Z_1,...,Z_k)))}&=
\mathcal{L}_{[V,W]}A(Z_1,...,Z_k)\\
&= \color{blue}{[V,W]A(Z_1,...,Z_k)}.\tag{$e4$}
\end{align*}
So we got first parts of right side of your thesis. Now take 'red' part for $i_0 = 1,...,k$. We have (I neglect minus sing to keep it shorter):
\begin{align*}
\color{green}{V\big(A(Z_1,...,[W,Z_{i_0}]...,Z_k)\big)} + \mathcal{L}_WA(Z_1,...,[V,Z_{i_0}],...,Z_k)
&= \\ \color{green}{V\big(A(Z_1,...,[W,Z_{i_0}]...,Z_k)\big)} &+\\ \Bigg(\color{orange}{W\big(A(Z_1,...,[V,Z_{i_0}]...,Z_k)\big)} -\color{purple}{\bigg(\sum_{j\neq i_0}^kA\big(Z_1,...,[W,Z_{j}],...,[V,Z_{i_0}]...,Z_k)\big)\bigg)} -A\big(Z_1,...,[W,[V,Z_{i_0}]]...,Z_k)\big)\bigg) \Bigg).
\end{align*}
and similarly for second 'red' part and same $i_0$:
\begin{align*}
\color{orange}{W\big(A(Z_1,...,[V,Z_{i_0}]...,Z_k)\big)} + \mathcal{L}_VA(Z_1,...,[W,Z_{i_0}],...,Z_k)&=\\ \color{orange}{W\big(A(Z_1,...,[V,Z_{i_0}]...,Z_k)\big)}&+\\\Bigg(\color{green}{V\big(A(Z_1,...,[W,Z_{i_0}]...,Z_k)\big)}-\color{purple}{\bigg(\sum_{j\neq i_0}^kA\big(Z_1,...,[V,Z_{j}],...,[W,Z_{i_0}]...,Z_k)\big)\bigg)} -A\big(Z_1,...,[V,[W,Z_{i_0}]]...,Z_k)\big)\bigg) \Bigg).
\end{align*}
Green and orange parts cancel immediately. Since $i_0 = 1,...,k$, the purple part will cancel when summing over $i_0$:
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{i_0=1}^k\sum_{j\neq i_0}^kA\big(Z_1,...,[W,Z_{j}],...,[V,Z_{i_0}]...,Z_k)\big) = \sum_{i_0=1}^k\sum_{j\neq i_0}^kA\big(Z_1,...,[V,Z_{j}],...,[W,Z_{i_0}]...,Z_k)\big).
\end{align*}
Combining above cancellations with $(e4)$ and summing over $i_0$, we get:
\begin{align*}
&\mathcal{L}_V{(\mathcal{L}_WA) (Z_1,...,Z_k)} - \mathcal{L}_W{(\mathcal{L}_VA) (Z_1,...,Z_k)} = \color{blue}{[V,W]A(Z_1,...,Z_k)} - \sum_{i_0=1}^k\bigg( A\big(Z_1,...,[W,[V,Z_{i_0}]],...,Z_k)\big) -A\big(Z_1,...,[V,[W,Z_{i_0}]],...,Z_k)\big)\bigg)\\
&=\color{blue}{[V,W]A(Z_1,...,Z_k)} - \sum_{i_0=1}^k A\big(Z_1,...,[W,[V,Z_{i_0}]]-[V,[W,Z_{i_0}]],...,Z_k)\big)\\
&=\color{blue}{[V,W]A(Z_1,...,Z_k)} - \sum_{i_0=1}^k A\big(Z_1,...,\mathcal{L}_{[V,W]}Z_{i_0},...,Z_k)\big)\\
&=\mathcal{L}_{[V,W]}A(Z_1,...,Z_k),
\end{align*}
where second equality is from linearity of tensor field and third from (1) and (2).
Sorry for any mistakes along the way, it's quite straightforward, but long to write and not get lost.
